# Chrome cannot seek mp4 video in asset library

Tags: video, chrome, asset-library

I have created a new asset library in Sharepoint 2013 and uploaded an mp4 file.
I can play the video in Chrome (Version 64.0.3282.167 (Official Build) (64-bit))  but I cannot seek it neither forward nor backward.
Is [Byte serving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_serving) related ?
It also works fine in Firefox, Internet Explorer, Edge.